# Stark's formula for the j-invariant

Tags: number-theory, elliptic-curves, modular-forms

In his paper *On the "gap" in Heegner's proof* (which you can find : [here](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=241384)) Stark gives the following formula for the $j$-invariant (for some $\tau \in \mathcal{H}$ and $q=e^{2i\pi\tau}$)

$$ j(\tau) = \frac{(1 + 240 \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sigma_3(n) q^n)^3}{q\prod_{n=1}^\infty (1  - q^n)^{24}} $$

with $\sigma_k(n) = \sum_{d|n} d^k$.

On the other hand the formula that I know for the $j$-invariant is :
$$
j(\tau) = 12^3 \frac{g_2^3(\tau)}{g_2^3(\tau) - 27g_3^2(\tau)}
$$

with
$$
g_2(\tau) = 60\sum_{(m,n) \neq (0,0)} \frac{1}{(m\tau +n)^4} = \frac{(2\pi)^4}{2^23}(1 + 240 \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sigma_3(n)q^n)
$$
and
$$
g_2(\tau) = 140\sum_{(m,n) \neq (0,0)} \frac{1}{(m\tau +n)^6} = \frac{(2\pi)^6}{2^23^3}(1 - 504 \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sigma_5(n)q^n)
$$

**My question** : How do you get Stark's formula from where "I" am ? (I obviously see how we get the "top" part of the fraction). i.e. why is it true (if it is) that
$$
g_2^3(\tau) - 27g_3^2(\tau) = q\prod_{n=1}^\infty (1  - q^n)^{24}
$$
modulo multiplication by some constant.

Answer (score 1):

Stark's formula is simply the $q$-expansion of the $j$-invariant. As you pointed out,
$$j(\tau)=1728\frac{g_2(\tau)^3}{\Delta(\tau)}=j(\tau)=1728\frac{g_2(\tau)^3}{g_2(\tau)^3-27g_3(\tau)^2}.$$
By taking the $q$-expansion, i.e. writing the Fourier expansion as a Laurent series, we get
$$ j(\tau) = \frac{(1 + 240 \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sigma_3(n) q^n)^3}{q\prod_{n=1}^\infty (1  - q^n)^{24}}, $$

or better yet,

$$j(\tau)=1728\frac{(1 + 240 \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sigma_3(n)q^n)^2}{(1 + 240 \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sigma_3(n)q^n)^2-(1 - 504 \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sigma_5(n)q^n)^2}.$$
Let's take a look at the $q$-expansion of the modular invariants:
$$g_2=1+240q+2160q^2+6720q^3+⋯$$
$$g_3=1−504q−16632q^2−122976q^3-\cdots.$$
Now we can express $\Delta$ as
$$Δ=\sum_{n=1}^∞τ(n)q^n=q−24q^2+252q^3⋯.$$
Finally, we have the $j$-invariant which
 simplifies to something like $$j(\tau)=\frac{1}{q}+744+196884q...\quad\quad q=e^{2\pi i \tau}.$$
I don't remember the expansion beyond that but if you need any sources I recommend *A First Course in Modular Forms* by Diamond and Shurman or the first chapter of Silverman's *Advanced Topics in the Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves*

Comment: I don't think your answer really answers my question since I was asking precisely why the two identities were equal, sorry. On the other hand your advice to look in Diamond Shurman was really good and the answer is given in proposition $1.2.5$. If you want to write a short summary of what is said there then I will gladly accept your answer. (The reason is that $\eta^{24} = q\prod_{n = 1}^\infty(1-q^n)^{24}$ and $\Delta$ live in the same one dimensional space $\mathcal{S}_{12}(SL_2(\mathbb{Z}))$

Comment: Why don't you answer it? Just add it under your question. That way there can be my $q$-expansion method and your Dedekind eta function method. I'll admit I've never heard of the modular discriminant expressed as a factor of the Dedekind eta function, but then again I usually only consider the $j$-invariant strictly in terms of an elliptic curve or a lattice over $\mathbb{C}$. In fact, I believe a third way to show the relation would be to somehow show a relation on the $c$-invariants since two elliptic curves are isomorphic if and only if they have the same $j$-invariant.

Comment: But I am curious about the last sentence of your comment. Are you suggesting they are equal because they are both weight 12 cusp forms? They are indeed elements of $\mathcal{S}_k(SL_2(\mathbb{Z}))$ which is an ideal of the ring of modular forms $\mathcal{M}_k(SL_2(\mathbb{Z}))$ but that hardly makes them equal. In fact, now that I think about it, I believe it can be shown that the eta function necessarily factors into a sum of (possibly normalized) Eisenstein series. I think that's in chapter 3 or 4 in Diamond and Shurman or wherever they discuss dimension formulas

Comment: Relationships between $J$, $\lambda$, and $\eta$ [are well-known](http://dlmf.nist.gov/23.19); one could use e.g. theta function machinery to prove these interrelations. Apostol's *Modular Functions and Dirichlet Series in Number Theory* ought to have something you can use. So, @V.deDaruvar, what sort of answer were you expecting again?

Comment: @J.M. I was trying to remember the title of that book yesterday! Great reference

Comment: It's all very well explained in Diamond and Shurman. It all comes down to showing that $\mathcal{S}_{12}(SL_2(\mathbb{Z}))$ is one dimensional. As I said in my question and in my comment I wasn't looking for the $q$ expansion but for a proof of the particular relationship $\Delta = \lambda q\prod_{i=1}^\infty (1 - q^n)^{24}$ (it turns out $\lambda = (2\pi)^{12}$), that's why I don't accept your answer (but thank you very much for posting it anyway it was interesting).

Comment: @V.deDaruvar No one is upset; you were looking for a particular relation concerning the $j$-invariant. As I said, there are many, including using the Dedekind eta function, $q$-expansion, and I suspect on the $c$-invariants. Mine wasn't the one you were looking for. It happens. I'm glad I was able to point you in the right direction as far as a reference goes.

Comment: @V.deDaruvar, then might I suggest that you write your very own answer to your question, if you think you have something more satisfactory than Brent's? The system allows for answering your own questions.